# Unable to push data to Firebase array field

Tags: arrays, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying to push two strings to an array field within Firebase, but I am not having much luck.

Here is the code we currently have in place

```
chatsRef.doc(task.id).set({
      'members': {
        ([assignee.id, task.ownerId])
      }
    });
```

And this is the error we seem to be getting:

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
'dart:ui/hash_codes.dart': Failed assertion: line 17 pos 12: 'o is! Iterable': is not true.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
chatsRef.doc(task.id).set({
  'members': [assignee.id, task.ownerId]      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying add a list into a map. A map should have a key.
So you can follow @Peter Kotlai like:

```
    chatsRef.doc(task.id).set({
      'members': [assignee.id, task.ownerId]      
    });
```

or add a key like:

```
    chatsRef.doc(task.id).set({
      'members': {
       'mykey': [assignee.id, task.ownerId],
      }      
    });
```

Comment: to my knowledge array doesn't have a key this is set by firebase